# Graph Database: TinkerPop/Blueprints vs W3C Linked data

Tags: semantic-web, graph-databases

Looking for an infrastructure for network analysis for heterogeneous (multiple node types (multi-mode), multiple edge type (multi-relation) and multiple descriptive features (multi-featured)) networks, I've noticed that there are two standard stacks in the Graph Database world:

*On one hand* we have the [ThinkPop/Blueprint](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/) [property graph model](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Property-Graph-Model). It is supported by [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/), [OrientDB GraphDB](http://www.orientdb.org/orient-db.htm), [Dex](http://www.sparsity-technologies.com/dex.php), [Titan](http://thinkaurelius.github.com/titan/), [InfiniteGraph](http://objectivity.com/products/infinitegraph/overview), etc.

The Tinkerpop stack includes the [Blueprint](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/) property graph model interface, the [Gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki) graph traversal language, and the [Furnace](https://github.com/tinkerpop/furnace/wiki) graph algorithms package.

*On the other hand* we have [W3C's Linked Data technology stack](http://www.w3.org/standards/semanticweb/data), which is supported by [AllegroGraph](http://www.franz.com/agraph/allegrograph/), [4store](http://4store.org/), [Oracle Database Semantic Technologies](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/semantic-tech/index.html), [OWLIM](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim), [SYSTap BigData](http://www.systap.com/bigdata.htm), etc.

Semantic data is represented using [RDF](http://www.w3.org/RDF/)/[RDFS](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/)/[OWL](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/), and can be queried using [SPARQL](http://www.w3.org/2009/sparql/wiki/Main_Page) On top it offers [rules](http://www.w3.org/Submission/SWRL/) and [reasoning](http://www.w3.org/standards/semanticweb/inference) capabilities.

Now, suppose that I want to represent heterogeneous data in a graph database, and analyse such data (statistics, relations discovery, structure, evolution, etc.) (I know these terms are wide and vague) - **What are the relative strengths of each model for various types of network analysis tasks? Do these two models complement each other?**

Answer (score 7):

Couple things, your exemplars of linked data stacks are all triple stores.  You would start building a linked data application by first getting your triple store set up, but calling a database a linked data stack is incorrect imo.  That's also an incomplete list of triple stores, there is also [Sesame](http://openrdf.org), [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net), [Mulgara](http://mulgara.org), and [Stardog](http://stardog.com).  Sesame and Jena kind of pull double duty, they're the two de-facto standard Java APIs for the semantic web, but both provide triple stores that come bundled with the APIs.  I also know that both Cray and IBM are working on triple stores, but I don't know much about either at this point.  I do know that Stardog works well with the TinkerPop stack and that it's basically a drop in and start writing Gremlin queries against the RDF.

I think the strengths of RDF/OWL is that you 1) get a real query language 2) they're w3c *standards* and 3) you get reasoning, if the triple store supports it, for free (more or less -- you still have to write an ontology).

With RDF/OWL/SPARQL being standards, it makes it quite easy to pick up and move to a new triple store with a different feature set should you need to, your data is already in a common format that everyone understands and any application logic encoded as queries are completely portable.  And in most cases, you'd be writing against either the Sesame or Jena APIs, or working over SPARQL protocol, so you might need to only change your config/init.  I think that's a big win in the early prototyping phases.

I also think that RDF/OWL especially combined w/ reasoning and the kinds of complex SPARQL queries that you can create with the new SPARQL 1.1 really suit themselves well to building complicated analytic applications.  Also, I think that the impression that most people have that RDF triple stores don't scale is no longer correct.  Most triple stores at this point easily scale into the billions of triples and have very competitive throughput numbers as well.

So based on what I think you might be doing, I think semweb might be a better bet for you.  I did a similar project a few years back using RDF & RDFS for the backend fronted by a simple Pylons based webapp and was very happy with the results.